# What does `use omp_lib` actually do?

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

According to [this](https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/OpenMP-Fortran.html) guide, one needs to include `use omp_lib` to enable openmp functionality. However, if I compile with `ifort -qopenmp` my code executes fine and I get the expected speed up, regardless if `use omp_lib` is used or not.

So what does `use omp_lib` do and should I include this line?

Comment: Try adding `Write( *, * ) omp_get_max_threads()` to your code and compiling with and without using the module. Assuming you are using `Implicit None`, if not there's no hope.

Comment: The `omp_lib` module brings interfaces to all OpenMP functions/subroutines. It's not required, but without it you don't have any compiler checking that the calls are correct, and you have to declare the types of the functions you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `omp_lib` is a module like any other. In general they contain constants, variables, type definitions and either module procedures (subroutines/functions) or interfaces to external procedures.

Just doing `use` brings all those names of those entities into the accessible namespace. **It does not affect the basic OpenMP functionality and directives at all.**

What exactly do these particular modules bring can be found either in the OpenMP official specification documents or in the documentation of a particular OpenMP library, e.g. the GCC's one [9.3 OpenMP Modules OMP_LIB and OMP_LIB_KINDS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenMP-Modules-OMP_005fLIB-and-OMP_005fLIB_005fKINDS.html). They indeed give you access to various named constants, derived types and functions and subroutines.

Comment: While can just link, the USE <…> will check the declarations when one complies, and import in any constants and variables.